# Print xyz values of an animating locator in Maya

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am trying to print out the xyz coordinates over time of a series of animating locators (named tracker1, tracker2, etc).  I  need to reconvert the locator's xyz data into a text file so I can then bring it into an alternate tracking program.  I know that what I need to do on a base level is run a mel or python script to print out the xyz data in a complete list within the script editor, but am having trouble with syntax.  The text file itself I can take care of, and I do not need a compiling script for all the locators at once either, though that would be great.  Any idea how to do this?

Revised:
Ok so here is what we have right now.
We are using this script, and successfully generating the xyz values for a single frame.
Example: item name "tracker1",
   frame: frame "1"
Script:

```
for ($item in `ls -sl`){  
$temp=`xform -q -t -ws $item `;  
print ($temp[0]+" "+$temp[1]+" "+$temp[2]+"\n");};  
0.1513777615 22.7019734 176.3084331
```

Thing is, we need this xyz information for every frame in the sequence (frames 1-68).
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Post what you have so far and we can help you work through the syntax issues.

Comment: Do you need to run this with an actual animation playback? Or can you just advance the timeline one frame at a time and dump the values?  The latter option is much easier

Comment: That is an option, but I would need to repeat this for 20 locators over 68 frames, which would be fairly time consuming.  I do not need to have an iterative process for all the locators at once, but it would be much easier to automate on a per locator basis.

Answer (score 2):

## Try this.

I wrote in *Python*, this can record **all selected objects' translate attr** at **every frame**,

and **write in to a `.txt` file**.

`start` frame and `end` frame was defined by time slider's *playback range*.

```
# .txt file path where you want to save, for example C:/trackInfo.txt
outPath = 'C:/trackInfo.txt'
# start time of playback
start = cmds.playbackOptions(q= 1, min= 1)
# end time of playback
end = cmds.playbackOptions(q= 1, max= 1)
#locators list
locList = cmds.ls(sl= 1)
if len(locList) > 0:
    try:
        # create/open file path to write
        outFile = open(outPath, 'w')
    except:
        cmds.error('file path do not exist !')
    # info to write in
    infoStr = ''
    # start recoard
    for frame in range(int(start), int(end + 1)):
        # move frame
        cmds.currentTime(frame, e= 1)
        # if you need to add a line to write in frame number
        infoStr += str(frame) + '\n'
        # get all locators
        for loc in locList:
            # if you need to add a line to write in locator name
            infoStr += loc + '\n'
            # get position
            pos = cmds.xform(loc, q= 1, t= 1, ws= 1)
            # write in locator pos
            infoStr += str(pos[0]) + ' ' + str(pos[1]) + ' ' + str(pos[2]) + ' ' + '\n'
    # file write in and close
    outFile.write(infoStr)
    outFile.close()
else:
    cmds.warning('select at least one locator')
```

---

## For moving time frame

#### 1. Use `currentTime` cmd

Mel:

```
currentTime -e $frame
```

Python:

```
cmds.currentTime(frame, e= 1)
```

#### 2. With a `for loop` and set start, end frame number

Mel:

```
// in your case
int $start = 1;
int $end = 68;
for( $frame = $start; $frame < $end + 1; $frame++ ){
    currentTime -e $frame;
    // do something...
}
```

Python:

```
# in your case
start = 1
end = 68
for frame in range(start, end + 1):
    cmds.currentTime(frame, e= 1)
    # do something...
```

Comment: It i actually faster to disable updating on screen (this is beneficial anyway) and then bake the data query bake and undo than updating time in a for loop.

Comment: @joojaa Yes! You're right. I totally forgot about it.
I'll update my answer later.